# Error in jenkins during sonar analysis caused by svn blame

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sonarqube, sonar-runner

When i run the jenkins task i get the following error

```
17:12:49.738 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor...
17:12:49.847 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: svn
17:12:49.847 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information...
17:12:49.863 INFO  - 843 files to be analyzed
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:11.026s
Final Memory: 31M/214M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w src/com/musigma/muPDNA/RESTClient/ServiceClient.as] failed: svn: E215004:
```

When i try to delete the .svn folder and run the sonar runner, it works fine. I have tried to ignore the svn files and svn folder, also i have tried to disable the blame option in the sonar but without any possible outcome.

Which is the right way to do this ??

its not mentioned anywhere. I want to eliminate the error caused by blame(svn) but I don't want to delete the ".svn" folder before the analysis(which is the only way i'm able to get it working)

Comment: svn: E215004 should indicate authentication issue.

Comment: You skipped the most important part of the error. It goes after `svn: E215004:`.

Comment: I don't want any svn related analysis from sonar. I want to disable the blame process(I want SonarQube to behave in such a way that svn is not present).

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: I tried with different versions of sonarqube- 5, 4.3.x and a few more. Same error with all versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In SonarQube v4, go to your project's dashboard and then to Project Configuration \ Settings (top right under the Search box).

Click the SCM Activity link in the Category list and change the "Activation of..." drop down to false.

[image]

You can change the default on the global settings page.

Comment: though this doesn't help if the project was never created automatically. I used gouessej's solution which worked for me :)

Comment: It also works for Sonarqube version 7.1 - Go to Administration->Configuration->SCM and set to Disable

Answer (score 14):

Just add the property `sonar.scm.disabled=true` into `sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties`. I have just tested it with `SonarQube 5.1.1`.

Answer (score 3):

In the last release of Sonar (SonarQube v 5.0.1), property is set to true in order to deactivate the SCM Sensor.
So choose "True" to disable SCM and solve this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

In Sonarqube server version Version 5.6.1
Click on Administration -> click on Configuration Dropdown and select General settings -> Click on SCM -> Select the true in Disable the SCM Sensor drop-down and save SCM settings(The default selected means is false).